# Load multiple files using the d3-fetch module

Tags: javascript, d3.js, riot.js

I try to load data from two different sources. After loading the data I want to use it within a riot tag file. But I do not understand how to load the second file, because I do not really understand the asynchronous call.

What do I have to modify in my code to get the data? Right now, the second data object is undefined. Here is my code:

```
import { csv, json } from 'd3-fetch'
csv('/data/stations.csv', function (stations) {
  json('data/svg_data.json', function (svg) {
    return svg
  })
  stations.position_x = +stations.position_x
  stations.position_y = +stations.position_y
  stations.animation_time = +stations.animation_time
  stations.text_x = +stations.text_x
  stations.text_y = +stations.text_y
    return stations
  }).then(function (stations, svg) {
   mount('metro-app', {
     stations: stations,
     svg_data: svg
  })
})
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [d3-fetch](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch) module makes use of the [Fetch API](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) and will, therefore, return a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for each request issued via one of the module's convenience methods. To load multiple files at once you could use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) which will return a single Promise that resolves once all Promises provided to the call have resolved.

```
import { csv, json } from 'd3-fetch'

Promise.all([
  csv('/data/stations.csv'),
  json('data/svg_data.json')
])
.then(([stations, svg]) =>  {
  // Do your stuff. Content of both files is now available in stations and svg
});
```

Here, `d3.csv` and `d3.json` are provided to fetch content from two files. Once both requests have completed, i.e. both Promises have resolved, the content of each file is provided to the single Promise's [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method call. At this point you are able to access the data and execute the rest of your code.