# Merging arrays that hold CSV data into one object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, d3.js

I've taken influence from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491885/csv-to-array-in-d3-js) to store CSV files in individual arrays, and it works. I'm looking to add about 8 more arrays that each hold the contents of a CSV file.

But how can I merge these arrays into one array of objects? ***Having an array of objects is critical for my subsequent application of these arrays***. What I have so far is below, but I'm not sure if it is correct or not?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
var dataCSV;
var dataCSV2;

var collection = {dataCSV, dataCSV2};

d3.csv("data/csv1.csv", function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.word = d.word;
        d.frequency = +d.frequency;
})
    dataCSV = data;
    console.log(dataCSV);
});

d3.csv("data/csv2.csv", function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.word = d.word;
        d.frequency = +d.frequency;
    })
    dataCSV2 = data;
    console.log(dataCSV2);
});

function merge(data1, data2) {
    collection = {data1, data2};
    console.log(collection);
}

merge(dataCSV, dataCSV2);
```

Ideally, I'd like the output of collection to be:

```
collection {
    dataCSV {
        word: ..., frequency: ...,
        word: ..., frequency: ...
    },
    dataCSV2 {
        word: ..., frequency: ...,
        word: ..., frequency: ...
    }
 }
```

Comment: Are you bound to using an old version of d3/d3-queue? You could make your life easier if you upgraded to v5.

Comment: I had no idea V5 was available... I'll look into it. What a solution for what i need look like in V5?

Comment: Have a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49240175/4235784) to [*"Load multiple files using the d3-fetch module"*](/q/49239474). `d3-fetch` module replaces the now deprecated module `d3-queue` in v5.

Comment: @altocumulus This is confusing, i may need to post another question

Comment: The solution from my answer I linked to is basically the same as the one proposed by @OriDrori's answer. However, v5 makes your life easier as there is no need to create new Promises yourself as d3 makes use of the Fetch API which will return Promises on its own, i.e. `d3.csv` returns a Promise. This is what you can see in my answer. Same technique, just shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of repeating yourself, create a single method that gets the data, formats it, and returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Then collect the results of several promises using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). Then you can collect both arrays in an object.

Example (not tested):

```
const getCsv = (url) => new Promise((resolve) => {
  d3.csv(url, function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) { // you can use a Array.map() instead for a cleaner solution
      d.word = d.word;
      d.frequency = +d.frequency;
    })

    resolve(data);
  });
});

Promise.all([ // load both csvs, and wait for the results of both
  getCsv('data/csv1.csv'),
  getCsv('data/csv1.csv')
])
.then(([dataCSV, dataCSV]) => { 
  const collection = { dataCSV, dataCSV2 };
  console.log(collection );
});
```

Comment: Hey man, just want to say this works great. But is it possible to have `collection` in the global scope when using `promises`?

Comment: You can assign the data inside the function to a global variable (like you do in your original code), but it's not sure that it'll we'll there when you'll want it. In your original code, add a `console.log(dataCSV1)` after the `d3.csv();`. The result will always be `undefined`. Because of the async call, code after the call is executed before the result arrives, and the only way to know when it's done is using a callback, promise, generator or async/await (which uses promises). My advice to you is to learn how javascript works.