# How to solve the problem 't is not iterable' when making a choropleth in D3 v6?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am trying to build a choropleth using d3.js version 6 now. Here is my code in JavaScript:

```
var height = 300;

var projection = d3.geoMercator().center([145, -36.5])
                   .translate([width/2, height/2])
                   .scale(2450);

var color = d3.scaleQuantize().range(['#b2182b','#ef8a62','#fddbc7','#d1e5f0','#67a9cf','#2166ac']);


var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .attr("fill", "grey");

d3.csv("files/VIC_LGA_unemployment.csv", function(data) {

    //Set input domain for color scale
    color.domain([
        d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.value; }), 
        d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })
    ]);

    d3.json("files/LGA_VIC.json").then(function(json) {

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    
            
            var data_LGA = data[i].LGA;
            
            //Grab data value, and convert from string to float
            var dataValue = parseFloat(data[i].unemployed);
    
       
            for (var j = 0; j < json.features.length; j++) {
            
                var json_LGA = json.features[j].properties.LGA_name;
    
                if (data_LGA == json_LGA) {
            
                    //Copy the data value into the JSON
                    json.features[j].properties.value = dataValue;
                    
                    //Stop looking through the JSON
                    break;
                    
                }
            }       
        }

        svg.selectAll("path")
            .data(json.features)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", path)
            .style("fill", function(d) {
            //Get data value
                var value = d.properties.value;
                            
                if (value) {
                    //If value exists…
                    return color(value);
                } else {
                    //If value is undefined…
                    return "#ccc";
                }
            });
            
    });
            
});
```

However when I tried to run the visualisation on Firefox, it says that I have a TypeError (t is not iterable), like in this image:[image: TypeError problem on the color domain.]

Can anyone being familiar with choropleth in D3 help me with this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Put `console.log(data);` just before `color.domain([...` . And post here the data you see in the console

Answer (score 1):

The answer is really a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49599691/how-to-load-data-from-a-csv-file-in-d3-v5), but the approach suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49239474/load-multiple-files-using-the-d3-fetch-module) is maybe a cleaner way to do it.

The [`d3.csv`](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch) (and `d3.json`) methods were changed between v4 and v5 to use the [`fetch`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52261136/difference-between-fetch-ajax-and-xhr) API i.e. with Promises. Therefore the basic way you use the functions should change from:

```
d3.csv('file.csv', function(data) {...});
```

To:

```
d3.csv('file.csv')
  .then(function(data) {...})
  .catch(function(err) { console.log(err); });
```

Where D3 v6 is still using this way introduced in v5.

You are getting the [`t is not iterable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/is_not_iterable) error because the [`d3.min()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/src/min.js) (and `max`) functions use `for...of` over the array to figure out the answer, and at the time you call them, the Promise of the data has not yet resolved.

You're already using `d3.json("files/LGA_VIC.json").then(function(json) {`  but maybe you can look into using [`Promise.all`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49239474/load-multiple-files-using-the-d3-fetch-module) like this and then refactor your code:

```
Promise.all([
  d3.csv("./data.csv"),
  d3.json("./map.json")
])
.then(function([data, map]) {
  console.log(`There are ${data.length} rows of data`);
  console.log(`There are ${map.features.length} features in the geojson`);
  // ... join data to features and then draw chloropeth
});
```